# Application Containing WebView Goes White While Exited YouTube FullScreen

Tags: android, video, webview, youtube

I've a put a WebView in my android app and loaded YouTube in it (Device SDK version 23). Everything worked fine till I went fullscreen with that video. But, when I tried to exit webview's fullscreen that whole application screen went white.

I've picked up two logcat lines with ERROR tag while I've clicked the exit button which may be needed:

```
08-20 19:34:22.846 28114-28271/test.webview E/chromium: [ERROR:deferred_gpu_command_service.cc(79)] No hardware renderer. Deadlock likely
08-20 19:34:22.846 28114-28271/test.webview E/chromium: [ERROR:deferred_gpu_command_service.cc(79)] No hardware renderer. Deadlock likely
```

I've uploaded a screenrecord of the event [HERE](https://www.dropbox.com/s/swazjtmmtd7vfa7/test.mp4?dl=0).

As logcat says it's a hardware problem. So, will it be unfixable? What will I do if most of my application's user get in this problem? They will mostly consider it as a bug and will uninstall my app after checking for update for sometimes.

**UPDATE:**

From [HERE](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=344087#c46) I've found someone commented that (on Sep 16 2014) it's have been fixed. But as *Google* can [remember](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=marshmallow%20android%20release%20date&spell=1&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjB8aK7_-XVAhXFqY8KHUI9CE8QvwUIIigA&biw=1366&bih=662) that Android M has been released on September 29, 2015. And, I've bought my device some months ago. I really can't understand what's going.

Comment: I have faced a white screen in the process of OneDrive MSA Login by means of OneDrive Android SDK. I have fixed it by installing [last WebView](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.webview) on the device. Did you try?

Comment: Tried, doesn't work.

Comment: I've also the same prob, and tried by updating webview as @isabsent said, but didn't work

Comment: I think it's happeing in only MTK devices, see what I've found :

`E/ACodec: [OMX.MTK.VIDEO.DECODER.AVC] storeMetaDataInBuffers failed w/ err 80000000

E/ACodec: cannot find aac bit rate`